# Getting a consistent and precise voltage for sampling

Tags: voltage-regulator, sampling

I have a 9V battery connected to an LM317T voltage regulator and it's regulating the voltage almost perfectly but I intend to use it for sampling and it fluctuates over a few mV. Generally between 1.628 and 1.63V.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to correct this effect or if it won't be a problem once my amplified signal is also applied?

[image]

Comment: You should use a voltage reference as a voltage reference.

Comment: Are you sure that noise isn't coming from the scopes A2D - what does the 9V battery voltage look like measured in the same way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that PlasmaHH
@Icy Reading with a multimeter the voltage stays at 1.64V unchanging. How could I check the ADC? It's a LCP1768 mbed micro controller.

Comment: Try looking at the battery voltage divided using a resistor voltage divider. @PlasmaHH is referring to band-gap voltage references, rather than voltage regulators.

Comment: Instead of a voltage regulator?

Comment: What is the time scale of your noise ? It might be feasible to filter it when you ballpark the noise bandwidth and setup your filter cut frequency .The LM317 is featured on the  www.badbeetles.com website but not for its noise .The LM317 is old enough to vote and I thought that it had died .It seems that somebody exhumed it and it is alive and well on Engineering stack.If your noise persists then choose a nice reference.

Comment: @Autistic The voltage changes almost every single sample so every 1/5000. I'll see if I can use a voltage divider instead. What do you mean by "choose a nice reference.". Thanks.

Comment: In the 1970s there was not much to choose from when it came to ICs and many christchurch design engineers lived out of Nat Semi databooks . Now the internet is full of beetles.

Comment: First try decoupling that voltage, see if you can reduce HF noise on it, with the capacitor close to the ADC. Also get earth paths as tight as possible in case a ground loop is picking up magnetic fields, though the plot shows no sign of periodicity (hum) that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

If it were treated as gaussian noise certain loose estimations could be made: -

- Peak to peak of the sample is about 10mV
- Divide by 6 (sigma) to estimate RMS -> 1.7 mV RMS
- Sampling rate is unimportant because it will fold down noise from the upper regions due to aliasing: -

[image]

The picture above has an arbitrary Y axis showing power but, the important point is the relative power of the aliased noise compared to the unaliased noise. Picture taken from [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiot_-RgsLJAhWCQxoKHWDVDa8QFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fseismo.berkeley.edu%2F~kirchner%2Freprints%2F2005_74_spectral_aliasing.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHGASPEUXvRcI_37gib6gHiTuMWUw&sig2=YbvJi_e0xvPKvEdHO9ps0g&bvm=bv.108538919,d.d2s&cad=rja) document entitled "Aliasing in 1/f noise spectra".

How much noise does the LM317 produce? The DS doesn't say and most linear regulators don't say either because they produce noise that is of no consquence for their intended target circuit.

How much noise does the ADC have in the LCP1768. I had a quick look but I didn't seem to find the figure but, inbuilt ADCs are usually quite crappy.

Altogether I think 1mV or 2mV noise isn't unreasonable given what you say you are using.

Have you tried using a low pass (anti-alias) filter such as a 10k and 10uF capacitor to see if the noise reduces?

Comment: So using this as an offset wouldn't be too bad once the signal is amplified and applied to it. Good to know thank you.

Comment: The only time I'd ever use a voltage regulator like this is when making ratiometric measurements where the output of the  "thing" being measured was subjected to the same wobbles as the ADC - but you still need an antialias filter.